# Chrome Developer Tools unresponsive since update 32.0.1700.76 m

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome itself appears to work fine but I'm having problems with Developers Tools.  After a short period of time it becomes unresponsive and the following dialog pops up...

[image]

Is this a known bug, can or will it be fixed soon?  Also, the meantime what should I do, how can I roll back to older working version of Chrome?

I use Chrome and Developer Tools extensively and this is causing a major headache, so any advise would be welcome.

Comment: Whenever you experience something that could be described as "a bug", please report it at http://crbug.com/new. Make sure that you [search](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=unresponsive%20bug%20cr=Platform-DevTools&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&x=m&y=releaseblock&cells=tiles) for existing bugs first (e.g. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334150).

Comment: You might want to downgrade: http://download.oldapps.com/Chrome/31.0.1650.39_chrome_installer.exe

Comment: If you downgrade you will probably want to disable auto updates. to do that create the following registry KEY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update\UpdateDefault to the REG_DWORD value of "0". [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/187207?hl=en&topic=1064255)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is a [known bug](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/1PgURxP9_-k) that got pushed with v32. I have not seen anything about fixing it yet though.

It happens with any model window (which includes devtools) or when Chrome is running in app mode.

Chrome isn't actually crashing and you can still continue to use it, but that will continually pop up with devtools open.

**The issue has been fixed as of today's (1/28/2014) update. Version: 32.0.1700.102 m**

Comment: This is the most horrible bug ever. You can't even just leave it there and ignore it because it will periodically focus and remove your focus on the JS console. VERY annoying

Comment: Agree with @StevenLu - Between this and the scroll bug where you can't use the mousewheel in scrolled divs and iframes, and the slowdown in switching between the panels in the debugger, I'd like to know what Google was thinking in releasing this pile of crap.  What happened to testing before release? It's not like any of the current bugs are obscure or hard to reproduce.  </endrant>

Comment: Along with the mousewheel, I've found that scrollbars aren't responding either. I can't click and drag them to scroll, but only use the wheel :/

Comment: @ogradyjd: The "funny" thing is that actually this bug is the __same__ as the scrollbar bug - they have the same cause. They have been *hacking* the scrollbar and this is the result of their incomplete hack.

Comment: I hate to be a +1 on this but I've encountered all of the above too. The crash dialogs, the broken scrollbars, and in my case I've noticed (not sure if related) that the bottom ~30-40px of a popup/modal window isn't always responsive and buttons in this "footer" area are hard/impossible to click.

Comment: Definitely a new bug since the latest release (Chrome reporting version 32.0.1700.76 m)

Comment: The actual [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=335248) shows Google is slowly working on the problem, as the flames keep pouring in.

Comment: I have the same issue on version *46.0.2490.80 m*

Answer (score 11):

I started getting this problem as well.

In searching, I came across this issue: ["Page(s) Unresponsive" error messages in 32+](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=335248).

As best I figured out, the bug is related to:

- Windows 7/8 with Aero Theme
- Scrollbars on pages (such as in the developer console)
- Pages with popups (in particular Window.open() calls)

I guess they are slated to push the fix into version 33...and maybe leave the stable* 32 how it is (I hope not).

So there are a few options:

- Switch away from Aero Theme until version 33 is in stable
- Upgrade to the beta channel, i.e. version 33
- Click on the Wait button every 30 seconds whenever the chrome developer tools is open (Don't try this at home).

---

Update:

- [Chrome has released a hotfix into the version 32 stable channel](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.ro/2014/01/stable-channel-update_27.html).

Comment: So does upgrading to the beta channel. Thanks @Xantix

Comment: Also note [Issue 334522](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334522) in 32 stable due to Aero Theme.

Comment: After changing to basic theme, you need to close/reopen the console window. Might seem obvious, but it caught me :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is resolved in Chrome Canary 34.0.1799.0. Read more:

[Issue 335248:  "Page(s) Unresponsive" error messages in 32+](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=335440)

Answer (score 0):

@elewinso, Alternate place to look for the same registry key to disable Chrome autoupdate is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Google\Update..

Also, is there a way I can get notified when the next update happens? or, when can I remove this key?

Comment: Disabling auto update, personally, goes against everything that is awesome about Chrome. As a developer auto update make things awesome as you can always target the latest chrome builds as users always will be on the latest. Disabling auto update only opens yourself to the pain that is IE.

Comment: Sorry Oliver, but as a (hobbyist, part-time) developer, having your tools crumble beneath you is the pits.  What would be awesome is if "stable" meant "stable", and hacks like this (apparently meant to work around a bug in a long-obsolete Synaptics driver) never made it into a production release.  Maybe this experience will change things, but the tarnish on their halo will still take a while to repair.

Comment: @Oliver, disabling auto-update is not the intention here, but uninstalling an annoying buggy version is. The latest version released is supposed to have the fix, and I'm re-enabling auto-updates, assuming Chrome does not ship more buggy versions.

Comment: It is very unlike Chrome to have a buggy release hence my original point. I do, however, see your points in staying on the last stable build you are happy with.
So for this exact issue not upgrading is a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade chrome to Version 32.0.1700.102 m  this fixes the problem