# Chrome "Unresponsive Page" false-positive (since Chrome 32)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Ever since Chrome updated itself to version 32, I have been experiencing aggravating bugs. One of the worst is when editing the DOM using the Web Inspector, and Chrome will about every minute start popping up this dialog, which yanks focus from the Web Inspector:

[image]

It's complaining about the Web Inspector itself being "unresponsive", when it really isn't, and nothing's gone wrong.

This particular page I'm messing with is making use of the [mutation-summary](https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/) library. Perhaps the bug in Chrome that thinks stuff is unresponsive could be related to setting various continuously-running setTimeouts. I say this because I observe similar behavior in the web app we build at work where this has also started happening (and is equally annoying).

The workaround is I believe it is possible to just ignore the dialog and work can continue. I wonder if anyone else (or everyone else) has been experiencing this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Developer Tools keeps crashing since latest update 32.0.1700.76 m](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184844/chrome-developer-tools-keeps-crashing-since-latest-update-32-0-1700-76-m)

Comment: I'm still getting this in Chrome today version 39 something.

Comment: That's crazy. Strange because I haven't seen it myself for months now (Windows 7 and OS X 10.10)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I started getting this problem as well.

In searching, I came accross this issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=335248.

As best I figured out, the bug is related to:

- Windows 7/8 with Aero Theme
- Scrollbars on pages (such as in the developer console)
- Pages with popups (in particular Window.open() calls)

I guess they are slated to push the fix into version 33...and maybe leave the stable* 32 how it is (although I hope not).

So there are a few options:

- Switch away from Aero Theme until version 33 is in stable
- Upgrade to the beta channel, i.e. version 33
- Click on the Wait button every 30 seconds whenever the chrome developer tools is open.

---

Update:

Chrome has released a hotfix into the version 32 stable channel. http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.ro/2014/01/stable-channel-update_27.html

Thanks to @probackpacker for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: omg thank you. this has been so frustrating. switching off aero fixed it for me. i even tried downloading canary, and it suffered from the same bug.

Comment: To be specific, Chrome is incorrectly reporting to windows that the scroll area is part of the window "chrome" instead of client area - so chrome never gets the mouse events it's expecting, causing it to assume a script is long-running. This has apparently been fixed in the Canary (development) build but has not yet been rolled into an update for the main branch. Avoid clicking in the area where the _stock windows_ scrollbars would appear to avoid this issue (ie slightly wider/taller than the new chrome ones)

Comment: It looks like the Chrome team was sufficiently chastened and pushed out a hotfix: [SuperUser question](http://superuser.com/a/704737/204664) [Chrome Release Notes] (http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.ro/2014/01/stable-channel-update_27.html) Still shocking that these bugs made it to the stable channel.

Comment: I'm still getting it while debugging pages (e.g. ASP.NET site and chose to debug by attaching to IIS). I did find a post on the [product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/CjX7L7MLzX4%5B1-25-false%5D) with regards to supplying `--disable-hang-monitor` as an argument when starting chrome (could be added to your desktop shortcut). Kind of a hack, but seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this as well on Windows, it seems that this will happen in general when using the browser (not only within the web inspector).  It also seems to happen more often when loading flash content (such as a game).  The browser and flash areas are responding normally, but the browser thinks that they are not for whatever reason.  Pressing wait seems to hide the dialog for a few minutes until it will re-appear again.

I've read that this bug is fixed in the next beta (version 33).

Regards,
Moses

Comment: They need to hotfix it, not punt to version 33

Answer (score 1):

I have also experienced [this issue](http://frankcode.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/chrome-32-broke-the-internet/). The change of theme workaround has worked, and the Chromium team has provided the following update today:

> ... We understand your frustration and are actively working to resolve
>   it. When you add that comment, it’s confusing the comments around
>   whether we’re able to fully fix it on canary. If we can confirm it’s
>   fully fixed in canary, we can merge into the stable channel and
>   everyone can get the fix. So please refrain from saying thatyou’re
>   having this problem, too. I assure you we’re actively working on a
>   fix.

This statement was taken from [Chromium ticket #335248](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=335248).

Comment: This whole situation is just rather unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

Okay here’s the solution you can do without changing your theme, right click on my computer, go to your System Properties, and then go to "Advanced", click on "Settings" under Performance, then check the below radio button.  This seems to stop it

[image: Windows Visual Effects]

Answer (score 1):

If the aero fix isn't working for you, download [Chrome Beta](https://www.google.ca/intl/en/chrome/browser/beta.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same issue with Chrome 32 (there are so many problems in the dev tools...) but it ONLY happens for me when I have the dev tools detached / undocked from the main browser window.
You might be able to avoid it by re-docking the devtools if you are using them in un-docked mode.

Comment: Interesting! I like to work side by side though. Can't do that, it seems. It always docks on the bottom.

Comment: @StevenLu if you click-and-hold the "undock" button, it has a sub-option to dock to the right.

Answer (score 0):

August 6, 2014 - I solved this by installing the latest Chrome Beta  https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html

Comment: No, the fix was in Chrome version 32.0.1700.102 m. We are currently on (at least) version 36.0.1985.125 m. There was maybe a window of not more than one or two weeks during which it would have required installing a Beta. This issue has otherwise been addressed for a long time. Did you have Chrome's auto-update switched off? (Is that even possible?)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in Chrome by following simple steps-
1-Go to Setting
2-Go to Advance Setting
3-Uncheck the "Use Hardware Acceleration when available".

Answer (score -2):

I fixed that problem by linking modem directly to my PC, didn't reinstall or change Chrome or anything. I skipped connection through my wireless router which I think was the problem from the start... now all the pages Chrome couldn't load are loading with no problem at all. Maybe it's time to by a new router...