# Google Chrome browser issue - Becomes unresponsive

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have Issue with Google Chrome version: 32.0.1700.102 (Official Build 246481) m.I got this message
"The following Page(s) have become unresponsive.You can wait for become responsive or kill them." after some period of time is elapsed
Exactly what this issue is saying? Is Google Chrome has to fix it or website I am trying to access has problem?
Please help me out..!

Comment: You should edit this question. As-is, it looks like a tech support question that doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: Related: [Why causes Chrome to make my Mac unresponsive?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/120723/22781)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a plugin running on the page causing issues. Your question is far too generic though - you haven't said which site, whether you're running any extensions or really anything at all which could help.

Comment: The page I am developing is having simple jquery plugin and it has grid which binds data to it.

Comment: So it's a page you are developing yourself? Your questions needs to include this sort of info... currently it is going to be impossible to provide any helpful answers.

Comment: Sorry for it I got this http://stackoverflow.com/q/21196189/3122164 link hope so this will be helpful to me. Thanks Chris for your help.!

Comment: Glad you found an answer, no worries.