# Latest Google Chrome Update on 17th Jan 2014 triggers Page(s) unresponsive alert

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

My project is built in .net v4.0. Since a Chrome browser update last week, every page triggers a "Page(s) unresponsive" alert. The alert occurs on every page regardless of whether or not the page uses ajax. This can't have just affected my project! Has anyone any advice on how to resolve this issue. ALl other browsers are fine.

Comment: What is indicated in the Console (F12) ? Any errors? Chrome does behave slightly differently to other browsers in some cases.

Comment: Thanks for tip but there are no errors indicated in the console

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Developer Tools keeps crashing since latest update 32.0.1700.76 m](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184844/chrome-developer-tools-keeps-crashing-since-latest-update-32-0-1700-76-m)

Comment: thanks - that post is regarding the same chrome version however might be being a bit slow on uptake but this alert is affecting all my clients who use chrome so is not just about the developer tools in my case.

Comment: does anyone know if chrome version 32.0.1700.76 has activated developer tools by default? This would explain why clients are experiencing the page unresponsive alert...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way round this I believe is to ask clients to install the beta version of Chrome (which includes a fix for this bug). To do this they should select to instal the Beta channel for Windows (or Mac) from here http://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel.

My application runs fine again using the beta version.

I suspect the next chrome version will be released soon anyway as this bug is causing widespread problems.

Comment: Another option is to not use Aero Theme in Windows, switch to basic mode. This was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196189/chrome-unresponsive-page-false-positive-since-chrome-32/21240206