# Page(s) Unresponsive when watching Pluralsight training video

Tags: video, video-streaming

I'm trying to watch [Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/sharepoint-2013-fundamentals) training videos and the following message keeps popping up:

[image: pages unresponsive]

It's not saying I need to install Java, update/upgrade anything... so I'm not sure how to fix this. I just keep hitting "Wait."

I've also tried dragging the message to one side of my screen, but then the message will reappear in the center of my screen.

Comment: I'm getting this constantly too. What I usually do is drag the message over to one of my other monitors and just let it sit there. If you hit Wait it just comes back over and over again.

Comment: @Dismissile I also tried doing that but it reappears in the middle of my screen.

Comment: I don't always use Firefox, but when I do, it's only when "Page(s) Unresponsive" annoying message comes up in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer from Pluralsight:

**They said:**

So sorry for the inconvenience. This is actually an issue that is on Google Chrome's end. [Latest Google Chrome Update on 17th Jan 2014 triggers Page(s) unresponsive alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231011/latest-google-chrome-update-on-17th-jan-2014-triggers-pages-unresponsive-alert)

We believe that if you download the Beta versions of Chrome, https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/beta.html, this behavior should be eliminated.